# Isomorphism between End$(V)\otimes A$ and End$_A(V\otimes A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and let $V,A$ be a finite dimensional vector space and algebra respectivly. I was told that there is a canonically isomorphism between  End$(V)\otimes A$ and End$_A(V\otimes A)$ where $A$ is considerd as a vector space in $V\otimes A$. I am stuck since I have truble even understand the structure of End$_A(V\otimes A)$ (unlike the clear notion End$_K(V\otimes A)$). Hope to get some help.

Comment: I think you should interpret $V\otimes A$ as a right $A$-module with $(v\otimes a) \cdot b = v\otimes (ab)$ -- so $V\otimes A$ is a free right $A$-module with rank $\dim V$.  Then $\operatorname{End}_A$ just means the $A$-module homomorphisms with respect to this module structure.

Comment: @mt_ Thanks, make much ,ore sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important fact to realize: $K^n\otimes_K A \cong A^n$. To see this, consider

\begin{align*}
 K^n\times A &\longrightarrow A^n \\
 ((v_1,\ldots,v_n),a) &\longmapsto (v_1a,\ldots,v_na)
\end{align*}
This is a $K$-bilinear map and therefore induces a linear map $\psi:K^n\otimes_K A \to A^n$. Let $e_i\in K^n$ be the $i$-th standard basis vector. If $B\subseteq A$ is a $K$-basis of $A$, then $B^n$ is a basis of $A^n$. On the other hand, the tensors $e_i\otimes b$ for $b\in B$ are a basis of $K^n\otimes A$. Clearly, $\psi$ maps this basis bijectively onto the basis $B^n$ of $A$, so $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Now, examples help. Let $K=K$, $V=K^n$ and let's say $A=K[X]$ the polynomial ring in one variable over $K$. Then, 
\begin{align*}V\otimes_K A&= K^n \otimes_K K[X] = (K\oplus\cdots\oplus K)\otimes K[X]
 = (K\otimes K[X])\oplus\cdots\oplus(K\otimes K[X]) 
\\ &= K[X]\oplus\cdots\oplus K[X] = K[X]^n
\end{align*}
Now, the $K[X]$-endomorphisms of $K[X]^n$ are just what you think they are, they are $n\times n$ matrices with polynomials as entries.

And this is quite generally the case. Since $V\cong K^n$ for some $n$, you will always get an induced isomorphism $V\otimes_K A\cong K^n\otimes_K A\cong A^n$. With this isomorphism, $\operatorname{End}_A(A^n)\cong A^{n\times n}$. 
But similarly, you have $\operatorname{End}_K(V)\cong K^{n\times n}$ and therefore, $\operatorname{End}_K(V)\otimes_K A \cong A^{n\times n}$, so the two objects are isomorphic as $K$-vector spaces.

Now, you claim that there is a *canonical* isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(V)\otimes_K A\cong \operatorname{End}_A(V\otimes_K A)$. This usually means that there is an isomorphism that can be expressed without choosing bases. It also suggests that the way to write it should be somewhat straightforward. I suggest

\begin{align*}
\phi:\operatorname{End}(V)\otimes_K A &\longrightarrow \operatorname{End}_A(V\otimes_K A) \\
\varphi\otimes a &\longmapsto \varphi_a,
\end{align*}

where

\begin{align*}
\varphi_a: V\otimes_K A &\longrightarrow V\otimes_K A\\
 v\otimes b &\longmapsto \varphi(v)\otimes ab.
\end{align*}

We now have to prove that this is actually an isomorphism. However, we can prove this by choosing bases, as long as we did not use any in the definition. You should be able to show that $\phi$ maps a basis bijectively onto a basis. I am currently too lazy to do it, but if you need more help leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Accept and +1. I will check that this is indeed an isomorphism, but it seems ok. I am also intersted in a "canonical graded isomorphism" between these two objects, but maybe this should be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most natural way to build an isomorphism is to take the following bilinear map $\operatorname{End}(V) \times A \longrightarrow \operatorname{End}_A(V \otimes A)$

$$
(\varphi, x) \mapsto \left(
\begin{matrix}
V \otimes A & \longrightarrow & V \otimes A \\
(v, y) & \longmapsto & \varphi(v) \otimes xy
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

and consider the induced morphism $\operatorname{End}(V) \otimes A \longrightarrow \operatorname{End}_A(V \otimes A)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am sorry and I don't understand what is the map and why it is an isomorphism.

Comment: If you struggle to understand my answer, I hope that you will be able to understand Jesko's one. Basically the idea is quite simple, if you know how tensors work.

Comment: Thanks, now after Jesko's answer I also understand yours. +1